# Flutter&GetX: The first dialog not working after open the second dialog in the new page when using the Get.toNamed()

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-get

This issue is related with [github #2502](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/59549741/184571169-01a030db-59a1-4618-a8c8-003a14e88b10.mp4).
I am using `GetMaterialApp` from this [package](https://flutter-test-exam-bug.web.app/#/github_2502).
I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.
How to make the function in the `first dialog` useable by using `Get.toNamed()`?

It happened when using the Get.toNamed().
It works fine with Navigator.push() but I need Get.toNamed for the web app.

The first page has a button that will show the first dialog.
The first dialog will show the order type button list.
When pressing an order type button, the program will find a new order of this type and open the second page with a new order data.
The second page has some work to do and this work will open the second dialog.
After finishing this work, the user will click on the back button back to the first page and find a new order again.

The problem is when the second dialog works on the second page.
The first dialog on the first page will not work.

[see video example.](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/59549741/184571169-01a030db-59a1-4618-a8c8-003a14e88b10.mp4)

[web example.](https://flutter-test-exam-bug.web.app/#/github_2502)

code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test_exam_bug/config/path/page_path.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

Future<void> _showMyDialog({required BuildContext context, required Widget child}) async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => child,
  );
}

class PageTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageTestState createState() => _PageTestState();
}

class _PageTestState extends State<PageTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget dialog_ = Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(PagePath.test2), child: const Text("Open second page"))),
        openDialogButton_ = ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => _showMyDialog(context: context, child: dialog_), child: const Text("Open first dialog"));

    return Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: Center(child: openDialogButton_)));
  }
}

class PageTest2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageTest2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageTest2> createState() => _PageTest2State();
}

class _PageTest2State extends State<PageTest2> {
  ButtonStyle buttonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.green);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget dialog_ = Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), child: const Text("I am second dialog"), style: buttonStyle)),
        openDialogButton_ = ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => _showMyDialog(context: context, child: dialog_),
            child: const Text("Open second dialog"),
            style: buttonStyle);

    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: SafeArea(child: Center(child: openDialogButton_)));
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any error text in terminal ?

Comment: There isn't any error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug.
When opening a dialog, the GETX ROUTE will change to the current page again.

Follow this in https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/2502